# Why does phpinfo() show version 7.4 but php -v show version 7.2.34?

Tags: ubuntu, php

when I run a file with `phpinfo()` , then result is PHP Version 7.4
but command line run `php -v`, but result is PHP 7.2.34

```
PHP 7.2.34-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 16:57:15) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.34-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Why am I seeing the discrepancy?

Comment: Because php -v shows php CLI versions

Comment: PHP-CLI is different from the PHP you are using in your web server. This is very common.

Comment: Please share more details and your debugging attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `phpinfo()` is the version which your website will be using to show PHP pages. The PHP that Apache/Nginx uses is different from the PHP command line version. They don’t interfere with each other.

Actually, you can compile and load different PHP versions you want to work with Apache as long as you configure Apache to properly load them. The PHP command line interface will never be used by Apache for parsing PHP pages.

The command line version of PHP, i.e. PHP-CLI, is simply there for the command line.